# PHP - Posted file is uploaded to server but returns PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, file, http-post

Though my file is uploaded, moved and named correctly onto the server, I'm getting this error in my logs;

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: myfile.mp4 in /mypath/myfile.php on line
```

Oddly it all seems to be working as it should. But the error is annoying. Any idea why am I getting the error?

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type: audio/mp4");  
    
    $replyid = "123";
    $audiourl = "myaudiourl.mp4";
    
            
    if (isset($_FILES["audio"]) && $_FILES["audio"]["error"] == 0) {
    $uploaddir = '/mypath/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['audio'][$audiourl]); 
    $oldname = $_FILES['audio']['name'];    
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'], $audiourl)) {echo  $replyid;   
    
    } else {echo "Failed upload";}  
    } else {echo "No file";}        
    
?>
```

Comment: I do not see "myfile.mp4" anywhere in the code. The error refers to a try to access a non existing index on an array.

Comment: Which is the array with a non-existing index?

Comment: The log should contain the exact line that is causing this problem `in /mypath/myfile.php on line ...`. Which line is that?

Comment: The line the PHP error logs gives me is this one: $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['audio'][$audiourl]);